# Bazaar merge questions

Tags: bazaar

1. Is it possible to merge only specific files and just copy the unselected files?
   I.E. i want to resolve conflict in all files except *.hex *.s19 and *.out. in those    files i want to take the .THIS file always (for example)
2. How i configure bazaar merge to be external and the builtin tool? i want to use the bcompare as my merge tool and not just as 4-way diff to resolve conflicts
3. i'm using beyond comapre software for resolving conflicts after merge.
   Today i simply run the bcompare.exe and then press launch in the resolve conflicts menu.
   can i run it with any parameters that i want? (i.E choose the center file as the . BASE file and configure the outut file name as the merged file)

thanks from advance
Gil Idelson

Comment: As Jelmer said, you should rather post separate questions then they can be answered separately and thus voted on and approved separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if it perhaps make sense to file three different questions.

I'm not sure about 2) and 3) but for 1:

A partial merge is not possible. You should be able to do the merge anyway and then just use

```
bzr resolve --take-this **/*.hex **/*.s19 **/*.out
```

to take the local versions of those files.

Comment: thanks.its exactly what i looked for . what ** stand for? (i run it with *) do you know how to make it run on all directories looking for *.out conflicts ?

Comment: @Gil: ** matches zero or more directories in a path. See `bzr help patterns` for more info