# bazaar merge questions2

Tags: bazaar

in my previous question on how to avoid merging specific files i received an answer 
see 
[Bazaar merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317099/bazaar-merge-questions)

the solution is running a resolve command that takes the .THIS files for specific files that i dont want to merge. (like *.hex, *.s19...)

My question is how i make resolve command to run on all the files in all directories without making batch file that contains all the directoreis names. (what will work but needs modifications every project)

P.S i know what * is stand for , what is the meaning of ** ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it means "subtree". In other words, subdirectories and their subdirectories, and their subdirectories, etc. So, "**/*.hex" would match all files with the "hex" extension in the current directory and anywhere in the subtree under that.

Comment: thanks. i play with it and i found out that every ** is for ONE sub-directory . for example , "bzr resolve --take-this ** / ** /*.i "(without the spaces) will go deep 2 levels in the direcotories tree

Comment: The double asterisk is interpreted by your shell, so its meaning can differ a bit. I use zsh, which expands any number of directories when it encounters a double asterisk.