# How to efficiently manage two diverging branches in Bazaar?

Tags: wordpress, version-control, bazaar

I'm currently attempting to use Bazaar (via Bazaar Explorer for Windows) to manage some WordPress sites.

Local and distant branches have naturally diverged: some files such as `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` are inevitably different.

As partial `bzr-merge` seems to be impossible (cf. [Bazaar merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7317099/4094098)), I'm looking for a efficient way in order to manage this two branches: reflecting changes made to a branch into the other (or *vice versa*) without having to *re*-commit diverging files each time.

Comment: What about doing a `revert` on those files right after the merge ?

Comment: I wonder if `pull` wouldn't be a more appropriate command (rather than `merge`). But is it possible to use `revert` after doing this?